# Azure Function App - referencing external library

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am facing an error in Azure Portal Function Apps written in C# script.

error CS0103: **The name 'ZipFile' does not exist in the current context**

I try to use nuget.exe install System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll, but I cant add that package either. Error is as bellow.

D:\home\site\wwwroot Unable to find package 
'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll'

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to add the reference via the standard AddReference menu option and searching for the dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all answers.
I had found the Answer. 
I had downloded the .dll file from Console,
*nuget.exe install 40-System.IO.Compression.FileSystem*
After downloading that , add the reference library

*#r "..\40-System.IO.Compression.1.0.0.2\lib\net40-client\System.IO.Compression.dll"*

*#r "..\40-System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.1.0.0.2\lib\net40-client\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll"*

After that , Error gets removed.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

Add the assembly and  import namespace as below. It works on my side.

```
#r "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem"

using System.IO.Compression;
```

Comment: Do you know why this works? This assembly is not in [the list of available assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies)...

Comment: @Mikhail Find one explanation, you can check whether it's right. It seems the document doesn't list all assemblies available. I found `ZipFile` is using `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1` locally, where I also find `System.Core`, `System.XML`, etc.
Same thing on portal `D:\...`. So I assume assemblies may come from this folder and function cli folder.